# Qt QML - handle navigation buttons?

Tags: android, c++, qml, qt5

#### Context:

Qt QML 5.6

I could not find related documentation to handle the Android navigation buttons in my QML app (triangle, square and circle, at the bottom of the screen).

Currently, when touching them, it just puts my app in the background. I would like to give them some logic.

#### Question:

Is it possible to manage those buttons in QML? Or will I have to deal with a c++ event handler? (If so, which code should one look after?)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Poor man's solution:

Within the Window or application window scope, use

```
    onClosing: {
      do_what_you_need()
      close.accepted = false
    }
```

In `do_what_you_need()`, you may call Qt.quit if it is ok.

Comment: This will also trigger when attempting to close the window on other platforms. Try wrapping with `if (Qt.platform.os == "android")`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to manage these buttons from the QML. In QML, those key presses are handled exactly like key presses on a keyboard. For example, `Qt.Key_Back` refers to the back key(triangle) and `Qt.Key_Home` refers to the  home key(square). Here is an example of listening for the  home key in QML:

```
Keys.onPressed: {
   if (event.key == Qt.Key_Home) {
      console.log("Square button(home) pressed");
   }
}
```

For more on the key enumerations in Qt, see this documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum

Comment: I tried that but, as an example, I cannot disable those buttons with that code. Even with event.accepted = false, it still put my app in the background. Logic is not executed here.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, example with ignoring the back button (do not minimize the app)

```
focus: true
Keys.onPressed: {
   if (event.key == Qt.Key_Back) {
      event.accepted = true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All these codes

```
focus: true
Keys.onPressed: {
   if (event.key == Qt.Key_Back) {
      event.accepted = true
   }
}
```

might work!! but some times won't because you loose focus on your container and suddenly the signals won't trigger so the best way to do it so far is following [this](https://www.qt.io/blog/add-qtactivity-to-existing-android-studio-project) guide on official blog